# Virtualenv creation seems to do nothing

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a problem setting up a Virtualenv on my web host server (to install python modules later on)

So far I tried this (over SSH):

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar xzf virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
~/usr/lib/python2.4 virtualenv-1.5.2/virtualenv.py ~/data/env
```

and

```
~/usr/lib/python2.4 setup.py install
```

I don't get any errors or output and cannot find the ~/data/env-directory that should be created. What is going wrong? Or what is the next step?

Comment: Why don't you use a binary package? What is your OS/distribution?

Comment: Why don't use setuptools' easy_install or pip?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg#md5=bd639f9b0eac4c42497034dec2ec0c2b
$ chmod a+x setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg
$ ./setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg
$ easy_install virtualenv
$ cd ~/data
$ virtualenv env
```

Comment: It says 'unknown command' when I enter: ./setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg

Comment: @Wienel: have you been able to `chmod`it? The setuptools `egg` is no more than a shell script, you have to execute it to install. Is `unknown command` an error you get executing the egg or is `./setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg` being unknown?

Comment: Yes, I checked this with a FTP client: I can chmod the file. But I still cannot execute it.

Comment: did you double-checked the file name? Have you got necessary permissions?